# DialogFragment not updating his layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview, dialog

I had a dialog fragment containing a listView, instantiated from the activity directly with the item list for the listView, something like that: UsersDialogFragment(usersList: List). The list was then handled by a simple ArrayAdapter and all was working just fine. 
Now requirements are changed and I need to show my dialog fragment, start the users list fetch and show a progress bar until the recyclerView is ready, so I came up with this:

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private val usersDialogFragment = UsersDialogFragment()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
//code for the activity
viewModel.usersList .observe(this, Observer { usersList ->
        usersList ?.let {
if (usersDialogFragment.isVisible) {
 usersDialogFragment.prepareAndShowUsersList(usersList,currentUser)
   }
}
....
//other code for the activity 
}
```

UsersDialogFragment

```
class UsersDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

private var usersList = ArrayList<User>()

private var currentUser: String? = null

private var userRecyclerViewAdapter = UserRecyclerViewAdapter(usersList,currentUser)

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users_dialog, container, true)
    usersRecyclerView  = view.findViewById(R.id.users_dialog_recyclerView)
    usersRecyclerView.adapter = userRecyclerViewAdapter
    return view
}

fun prepareAndShowUsersList(usersList: List<SapUser>, currentUser: String?) {
    usersList.clear()
    usersList.addAll(usersList)
    userRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
 //Now I would like to hide the progress bar and show the recyclerView
 //but even if these two methods are called nothing happens 
getDialog().findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.users_progresBar).visibility = View.Invisible
getDialog().findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.users_dialog_recyclerView).visibility = View.Visible
  }
}
```

FragmentLayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/custom_linear"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".fragments.UsersDialogFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/users_dialog_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/parent"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/users_progresBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So, the fragment is showing, the list is fetched, the activity calls the method "prepareAndShowUsersList" of the fragment, the list is updated, the adapter is notified but the recycler view stays empty and views visibility doesn't change.
I have tried with all kind of method to retrieve views like :
requireDialog().requireViewById - this.view?.findViewById - requireView().findViewById - this.dialog?.findViewById - requireDialog().requireViewById, even with inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users_dialog, container, false) or inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users_dialog, null) but progress bar keep spinning and list is not updated/showed.

Where's could it be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing the visibility to GONE? `getDialog().findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.users_progresBar).visibility = View.Gone`

Comment: How do you show the `userDialogFragment`? I'm guessing you're not referencing the right one and maybe leaking the fragment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
Today getDialog().findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.users_progresBar).visibility = View.Invisible/Gone works fine. Maybe the startup build fixed it (?).

I thought the same @Pawel, but there was nothing else than "private val usersDialogFragment = UsersDialogFragment()" and "usersDialogFragment.show() when menu item it's selected".
 
I fixed some other problems with recycler view width/height and now it works. Thank you